# Decouple the SSR presentation layer for ASP.NET Core Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, server-side-rendering

I would like to create an ecommerce web application in ASP.NET Core.
But, the client wants to change the front-end theme by themselves.
Is it possible to decouple the presentation layer (HTML/CSS/Javascript) from the application still maintaining it server side rendered?

Comment: I'd think you'll only have 2 options: store the preferred theme in the database per user OR use a non-httponly cookie that ONLY stores the theme and is being accessed by asp.net core during ssr (using `SupplyData`), and angular from the client-side

Comment: @Pieterjan Sorry for misunderstanding. It's not the user, but the client. I want to make it just like CMS, where they can change the HTML and css by themselves without touching the server codes. Still it should be SSR to be SEO friendly.